# How to build global callgraph for a project using clang

Tags: clang, llvm, static-analysis, clang-static-analyzer

Hi i want to generate a global callgraph for a project with thousands of lines and its includes file known before hand but no information about linking. I do not have projects make file.
Please guide me to  generate the required callgraph using clang.
Is there any other open source that can help me to do the same and build global callgraph for multi million lines of C code.

Comment: In general any project in C.

Comment: You could try some graph query on a graphstore generated with kythe. But in general this kind of question is either to broad or off-topic here.